# Magento 2 - Fresh Install

Tags: composer-php, magento2

Creating a Fresh m2 install. Following the usual steps we have. Instailling it via composer.

```
composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition
```

But then errors with the below.

Any ideas?

```
 composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition
Creating a "magento/project-community-edition" project at "./project-community-edition"
Warning from repo.magento.com: You haven't provided your Magento authentication keys. For instructions, visit https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html

In CurlDownloader.php line 617:

  The "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/2 404 ):
  {"warning":"You haven\u0027t provided your Magento authentication keys. For instructions, visit https:\/\/devdocs.magento.com\/guides\/v2.3\/install-gde\/prereq\/connect-auth.html"}


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package> [<directory> [<version>]]]
```

Tried a couple of options but all get the same answer.

Comment: During this process, before downloading Magento, you would be asked to Insert your repo.magento.com username and password. For repo.magento.com username and password, log in to Magento Marketplace and select My Account from the top-right corner. Now click Access Keys and Generate your new SECURE KEYS. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/install-magento-2-composer/

Comment: Yeah, thats normally the case. But it doesn't get to that part.

Comment: The installation instructions are pretty clear what to do if that does not work: _"Contact Magento support for help."_ [ref](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/composer.html). See as well: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with composer. You need to update the Magento keys in composer using the below commands, because composer is not asking for the keys.

Try this:

`composer global config http-basic.repo.magento.com <public_key> <private_key>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks man! It woked. This is not even described in official document.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the command

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition projectname
```

there's a single space after `https://repo.magento/com/`
This worked for me. Hope this helps.